# I'm forced to do npm install --force

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm having a dependency conflict when doing `npm i` in my React project.

This project was not started by me, but by an external company, and now it is my turn to modify the code with the tasks assigned to me.

The problem is that to update or install a package, I get several errors, forcing me to use `npm i --force`.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: amchart4-react@1.0.4
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR! react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.11.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR! @emotion/react@"^11.8.1" from react-select@5.7.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-select
npm ERR! react-select@"^5.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 29 more (@emotion/use-insertion-effect-with-fallbacks, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from amchart4-react@1.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/amchart4-react
npm ERR!  amchart4-react@"^1.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from amchart4-react@1.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/amchart4-react
npm ERR! amchart4-react@"^1.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: "Forcing" you to use `--force`? I don't think so. Note the error message says "Fix the upstream dependency conflict" as its first option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're experiencing a conflict with peer dependencies in your project. The package amchart4-react is requiring a version of React that is either ^15.0.0 or ^16.0.0, while your project is using react@18.2.0. Here are a few ways you can attempt to resolve the conflict:

**Update the amchart4-react Package (If Possible):**

If there is a newer version of amchart4-react that supports React 18, you should update to that version. Check the package's documentation or its entry in the npm registry to see if a newer version is available.

**Downgrade React Version:**

If you don't need the specific features of React 18, you could downgrade to a version that satisfies both your project's requirements and the requirements of amchart4-react. For example, you could try installing react@16.14.0, which seems to be the version that's compatible with amchart4-react.

1. npm install react@16.14.0 react-dom@16.14.0

Use --legacy-peer-deps:
You can try running the install command with the --legacy-peer-deps flag, which tells npm to ignore the peer dependencies and install the package anyway.

---

2  npm install --legacy-peer-deps

---

Consider Alternative Libraries:
If you're unable to resolve the conflict by updating or downgrading packages, you might need to look for an alternative to amchart4-react that supports your current React version.

Manual Resolution (Not Recommended):
As a last resort, you could manually edit the package.json file of amchart4-react to change the peer dependency requirement. However, this is generally not recommended, as it can lead to unexpected behavior and makes your project harder to maintain.

Remember that resolving dependency conflicts can sometimes lead to other issues, particularly if other parts of your code rely on specific versions of the conflicting packages. Always thoroughly test your application after making changes to dependencies to ensure that everything continues to work as expected.

Comment: This seems like it was generated by an LLM.

Comment: @DaveNewton agree. Should this be flagged in any way?